# Using RMO, how can I get the list of Local Subscriptions from SQL Server?

Tags: .net, sql-server, replication, rmo

Using SQL Server Management Studio, it is easy to see the list of of Local Subscriptions on the subscriber database under the Replication folder. My question is how do I get that list programmatically . I know that I can use RMO to [create a subscription](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms147314%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). I want to know how to get a list of all of the existing Local Subscriptions.

Comment: It can be useful to somebody (like me) to know how to do this without RMO.
exec sp_helpreplicationdboption @reserved = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Publication.EnumSubscriptions Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.replication.publication.enumsubscriptions.aspx) returns the subscriptions that subscribe to a publication.  This would be the equivalent of executing sp_helpsubscription or sp_helpmergesubscription.

You can also connect to a Subscriber, get the [ReplicationDatabaseCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.replication.replicationdatabasecollection.aspx), and enumerate through the replicated databases subscriptions.  Here is an example:

```
// Connect to the Subscriber
subscriberName = "SubscriberName";
subscriberConnection = new ServerConnection(subscriberName);
subscriberConnection.Connect();

// Get Subscriber replication databases
ReplicationServer subscriberServer = new ReplicationServer(subscriberConnection);
ReplicationDatabaseCollection subscriberReplicationDatabases = subscriberServer.ReplicationDatabases;

// Enumerate Subscriber replication databases
foreach (ReplicationDatabase subscriptionDatabase in subscriberReplicationDatabases)
{
    foreach (MergePullSubscription mergePullSubscription in subscriptionDatabase.MergePullSubscriptions)
    {
        // do something...
    }
}
```

Comment: This works when you are connected to the publisher database. But it doesn't seem to work when you are connected to the subscriber database.

Comment: Hi @epotter, I added an example how to connect to the Subscriber and enumerate through the local subscriptions.